# Moving an image ... javascript declare variables as string

Tags: javascript, variables

When you click a button the variable which contains the position is declared as string!
This is the html code:
http://insane96mcp.altervista.org/corsa.html
And here's the javascript code:
http://insane96mcp.altervista.org/corsa.js

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/186560) Please also clarify exactly what your code doesn't currently do that you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
pxMove=(Math.random()*10).toFixed();
```

`toFixed` will convert your number to string, and the plus operator in the next line will then concat it instead of summing. If you want to round it and transform to integer, you can use `Math.round`:

```
pxMove = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
```